# Labels appear and disappear for no apparent reason using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling, rendering

I'm going through the Alaska sample data tutorial for QGIS 2.2.0. Some of the lake labels appear and disappear at different scales when zooming. At 1:314,460 Becharof is visible, but Lower Ugashik doesn't appear until 1:157,230. It seems like others have had similar problems.

I have played with the rendering and placement dialogs to no avail. Even if I don't have the "magic combination" of parameters set, shouldn't they all behave the same?

For my needs, this may well render (no pun intended) the program useless. I need it to print labels when I need them!

Comment: Would you be able to edit your Question to include links to support your assertion that "It seems like others have had similar problems", please?

Comment: @polygeo, I googled this problem (qgis+disappearing+labels+zoom) or somesuch and found a number of similar problems (I think on here also). I did not document the sources. Dakcarto answered the question about the labeling bug being addressed in upcoming version 2.4.

Answer (score 6):

Try turning OFF geometry simplification for the layer in the Layer Properties dialog:

[image]

This (actually an issue with resultant invalid geometries being unlabelled) has been fixed, and will be included in upcoming 2.4 release (within a month).

Comment: Related issues on the QGIS tracker: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/9655, http://hub.qgis.org/issues/9673

Comment: thanks for the response. I unchecked "simplify geom" to no avail. I believe the other parameters are properly selected to always display the lake labels. I have no options checked under LABELS > RENDERING other than "show all labels...". I don't think there is anything that would override this selection that would kill label output?

Some lakes keep their labels when zooming, but Lower Ugashik comes and goes. I will anxiously await the new version.

Comment: do I understand correctly that the lake may not be labeled due to geometry errors? I ran what I believe is the proper process to correct any errors on the layer, but none showed up. I wonder if other are seeing the same error with the Alsaka sample data? Is it perhaps something else?

Comment: Well, a polygon will be clipped to the visible map extent prior to being labelled (unless using 'whole' polygon for centroid labeling). If the polygon has a complex perimeter, e.g. shoreline, then the extent clipping may create an invalid, but render-able polygon, i.e. not labeled, though. In upcoming 2.4, there are routines to try and fix such polygons on-the-fly, allowing for more labels to be shown.

Comment: This is still a problem in 3.14.1. The labels appeared after unchecking simplify geometry